# Проблема nodejs

Tags: node.js, centos, pm2

Установил pm2 на centos,при старте приложения вижу только "[PM2] Spawning PM2 daemon with pm2_home=/root/.pm2"

В логе ошибка

```
    SyntaxError: Unexpected identifier
    at createScript (vm.js:56:10)
    at Object.runInThisContext (vm.js:97:10)
    at Module._compile (module.js:549:28)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (module.js:586:10)
    at Module.load (module.js:494:32)
    at tryModuleLoad (module.js:453:12)
    at Function.Module._load (module.js:445:3)
    at Module.require (module.js:504:17)
    at require (internal/module.js:20:19)
    at Object.<anonymous> (/usr/lib/node_modules/pm2/lib/Watcher.js:6:16)
/usr/lib/node_modules/pm2/node_modules/chokidar/index.js:150
  async remove(item) {
        ^^^^^^
```

Как её пофиксить? Заранее спасибо

Answer (score 0):

Вопрос решён установкой новой версии. Была нода версии 10.16.2, сейчас 12.13.0

Comment: Хотя бы укажите, какую версию поставили и желательно какая была.

Comment: С какой на какую?

Comment: Была нода 10.16.2, сейчас 12.13.0